# Shared_buffer > 20mb can not start database?

Tags: postgresql

I am using a Postgres database and want to tweek the parameters. The problem is that when I set shared_buffer to a value larger than 20mb my server won't start. I am running it on Ubutu 8.10 OS with 1gb RAM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you are reaching the limit of shared memory regions.

Check /proc/sys/kernel/shmall and /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax.

More info here:
http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/database/RHDB-7.1.3-Manual/admin_user/kernel-resources.html

Comment: And here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC